Pages are loading and give error 504 gateway timeout
I am not able to see post and pages are consciously loading if we try to activate download manager plugin.
If we deactivate the plugin can see able page load but post are not coming on the pages.
WordPress version :Current version: 6.4.3
plugin version : Version 3.2.89
we have around 1100 posts that not upload on our website and pages are continuous loading.
And we have got 504 error gateway timeout.
plugin setting we have  chunk size 1024 kb chunk load option is disable
and download speed is 1096

This may occur when the server is unable to respond within a given time.
The cause is for this should be long-running PHP scripts which exceed the max_execution_time
You can change or increase the max_execution_time as follows

php.ini


max_execution_time = 120


.htaccess


If you can't access the php.ini, then try modify .htaccess. This file is located in the root directory where the WordPress is installed


php_value max_execution_time 120


wp-config.php


If you can't do both above, you can try add following line to wp-config.php


set_time_limit(120);


504 error usually occurs when a server take too much time to respond. Try increasing the max_execution_time setting in your php.ini file. Also you can confirm that if posts are available in your wordpress. You can read this article for further help.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query
